# Python split() replication

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to replicate the split function. I have looked around and found one that has helped a lot, the only problem with the code is the empty string is not displayed empty rather they have multiple Apostrophe for multiple different empty strings. the current code is

```
def mysplit(strng):

    words = []
    current_word = " "
    for char in strng:
        if char == " ":
            words.append(current_word)
            current_word = ""
        else:
            current_word += char

    words.append(current_word)
    return words


    print(mysplit("To be or not to be, that is the question"))
    print(mysplit("To be or not to be,that is the question"))
    print(mysplit("   "))
    print(mysplit(" abc "))
    print(mysplit(""))
```

The output that comes out

```
[' To', 'be', 'or', 'not', 'to', 'be,', 'that', 'is', 'the', 'question']
[' To', 'be', 'or', 'not', 'to', 'be,that', 'is', 'the', 'question']
[' ', '', '', '']
[' ', 'abc', '']
[' ']
```

I'm trying to get the outcome of

```
['To', 'be', 'or', 'not', 'to', 'be,', 'that', 'is', 'the', 'question']
['To', 'be', 'or', 'not', 'to', 'be,that', 'is', 'the', 'question']
[]
['abc']
[]
```

Comment: You need to initialize `current_word` with an empty string not a space.  Then, if you only append to `words` when current_word is not empty, you should obtain what you are looking for (which is not exactly how split() works btw)

Answer (score 2):

When you find your separator (space), you *also* need to check that you have a proper, non-blank word to add.

```
    if char == " ":
        words.append(current_word)
        current_word = ""
```

should be

```
    if char == " ":
        if current_word:    # If there is anything to append, do so.
            words.append(current_word)
        current_word = ""
```

Comment: Not working for the test case `print(mysplit("   "))`

Comment: You probably need the same check after the end of the loop, when you append the last word. That way you don't mess up if the input ends with whitespace.

Comment: Right; this answer is the crux of the change; boundary conditions "are left as an exercise for the student".

Answer (score 0):

First, you should remove the words.append(current_word) just before return words.

And then you can add a if using the strip function to remove spaces in front and at the end of a string (https://www.journaldev.com/23625/python-trim-string-rstrip-lstrip-strip)

```py
if char is " ":
    need_to_append, stripped_word = should_append(current_word)
    if need_to_append:
        words.append(stripped_word)
    current_word = ""
```

Final version :

```py
def should_append(word):
    stripped_word = word.strip()
    return stripped_word != "", stripped_word

def mysplit(strng):
    words = []
    current_word = " "
    for char in strng:
        if char is " ":
            need_to_append, stripped_word = should_append(current_word)
            if need_to_append:
                words.append(stripped_word)
            current_word = ""
         else:
            current_word += char
    need_to_append, stripped_word = should_append(current_word)
    if need_to_append:
        words.append(stripped_word)
    return words
```

Comment: this is a lot closer then what i had previously only problem how is it leaves the last word within the string out.

Comment: Oh I see, I've update my answer with a new function `should_append()`
 to know if we need to add the word or no.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this using enumerate and zip:

```
def mysplit(string):
    spaces = [ i for i,c in enumerate(string) if c==" " ] # indexes of spaces
    subs   = [ string[s+1:e] for s,e in zip([-1]+spaces,spaces+[len(string)]) ]
    return [ s for s in subs if s ] # filter out empty strings
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues. Please take a look into my solution

```
def mysplit(strng):

    words = []
    current_word = ""
    for char in strng:
        if char == " ":
            if current_word:
                words.append(current_word)
            current_word = ""
        else:
            current_word += char

    if current_word:
        words.append(current_word)
    return words


print(mysplit("To be or not to be, that is the question"))
print(mysplit("To be or not to be,that is the question"))
print(mysplit("   "))
print(mysplit(" abc "))
print(mysplit(""))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def mysplit(strng):
    words = []
    if(len(strng)== 0 or strng.isspace()):
        return words
        
    current_word = " "
    for char in strng:
        if char == " ":
                words.append(current_word)
                current_word = ""
        else:
            
            current_word += char

    
    words.append(current_word)
    for w in words:
        if(w.isspace() or len(w)==0):
            words.remove(w) 
    
    return words


print(mysplit("To be or not to be, that is the question"))
print(mysplit("To be or not to be,that is the question"))
print(mysplit("   "))
print(mysplit(" abc "))
print(mysplit(""))
```